# In VS Code I don't want Black to format my settings.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to use the Black formatter for my Python files, but not for my JSON settings.

I have these set in my settings.json:

```
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

I have tried to use the --exclude tag by adding the following to settings.json:

```
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--exclude /*\\.json/"
    ],
```

which is equivalent to a commandline call with `black --exclude /*\.json/`

I also tried

```
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--exclude /*\\.json/"
    ],
```

based on this post: [VS Code Python + Black formatter arguments - python.formatting.blackArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725888/vs-code-python-black-formatter-arguments-python-formatting-blackargs).

However, it is still formatting my settings.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black doesn't format JSON. What's happening is VS Code has it's own included JSON formatter and that's what is formatting your `settings.json`. Do you have a setting turned on like `"editor.formatOnSave"` turned on? If so then it sounds like you want to scope it to just Python files, e.g.:

```
"[python]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: Not sure about VC Code, since I do not use it.  Black does format json.

Answer (score 4):

You can also disable the formatting for JSON, by:

- going to the preferences with [ctrl+,] and disabling [JSON > Format: Enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaBz.png).
- opening the settings.json file (open palette with [ctrl+shift+p] and search for "settings json") and add the following line:

  ```
  "json.format.enable": false
  ```

Or you can also limit the formatting to python files, by adding this setting in the settings.json file:

```
"[python]": {
   "editor.formatOnSave": true
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Black does format JSON and for me, broke it:

```
╰─➤  black proj/
reformatted proj/schema.json
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.

╰─➤  git diff proj/schema.json | wc -l
299
```

Comment: For recursive searches, black will attempt to format any file that matches the `--include` regex, which defaults to `\.pyi?$`.  Perhaps your project has a different configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Black can and will break json files (as sqqqrly mentioned).

I generally only wanted to apply black formatting to python files, but I am setting up a CICD pipeline where I check for the git diff for files in a repo, which may include any number of file types, and it was going to be a bit fiddly to filter inside the pipeline.

Luckily, there's a flag `--force-exclude` we can use to enforce this (per [the docs](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#command-line-options)). It takes a regex, which we can use a negative lookahead to ensure only python files are formatted. (note: single quotes are required for bash, otherwise you get `bash: !\.py: event not found`)

```
[me@here]$ black /tmp/example.json --force-exclude '(^.*(?<!\.py)$)'
No Python files are present to be formatted. Nothing to do
```

Also, because it excludes the file, it's not added to the file count even if other files are formatted, just in case that's important to you.

```
[me@here]$ black /tmp/a.json /tmp/b.py --force-exclude '(^.*(?<!\.py)$)'
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file left unchanged.
```